# Unity 5.1 player control of secondary object relative to player object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, position

I've done a lot of searching but can't find a sollution to this problem.

What I want is to control a game object that rotates around the player object at a fixed distance based on right analogue stick input, indepentant of player movement. I also want the object to face outwards as it moves around the player.

I have left analogue stick set to player movement and working and have right analogue stick set up and tested so I know the input is working.

I've tried transform.rotate, RotateAround, .position and quaternions etc but can't figure it out or find anything that might help. I am fairly new to this so there's probably a simple sollution, I just can't see it!

Appreciate any help you might be able to give :) Thanks a mil

**EDIT 2: The second attempt**

**so I've got this so far now:**

```
public class ShieldMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target; //player shield is attaced to

float distance = 0.8f; // distance from player so it doesn't clip
Vector3 direction = Vector3.up;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (Input.GetAxisRaw("rightH"), Input.GetAxisRaw("rightV"))* Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    if(Input.GetAxis("rightH") != 0f || Input.GetAxis("rightV") != 0f)
    {
        direction =  new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("rightH"),Input.GetAxis("rightV"), 0.0f ) ;
    }

    Ray ray = new Ray(target.position, direction);
    transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance);

    if(Input.GetAxis("rightH") != 0f || Input.GetAxis("rightV") != 0f)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle,Vector3.forward*-1);
    }


}
```

}

I'd like it to be a smooth rotation of the shield around the player going to a new location instead of teleporting there. I've tried some lerps and some slerps, so far all I've been able to so is interpolate from one point on the circumference in a direct line to the new point. Can't think of a way to get it to rotate around the player as it does if you just rotate the stick. Hope that makes sense!

Any ideas you wonderful folk you?

Comment: Did you already took a look up to SmoothFollow camera script? It makes the camera follow player in certain angle and distance rotating to face him. You can adjust to your follower object as well and increment the position(x,0,z) as you move your stick. I can't test it right now but looking at script seems to be a good way to at last understand what you need to do...

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you :) Will post if it works :)

Comment: Checked it out, kinda get where it's coming from but I can't seem to get it going. I've posted a partial solution without the animation (since I can't get that bit working) above if you want to see what I've got so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres two ways of accomplishing what you want

*Please note: this has not been tested*

**With a custom normalized procession** (`0f` is exactly `Vector3.forward`, `1f` brings you back to `Vector3.forward`)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Follower : MonoBehaviour {

    float distance = 10f;
    Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;
    float procession = 0f; // exactly at world forward 0
    Transform target;

    void Update() {
        float circumference = 2 * Mathf.PI * distance;
        angle = (procession % 1f) * circumference;
        direction *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(Mathf.Rad2Deg * angle, Vector3.up);
        Ray ray = new Ray(target.position, direction);

        transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance);
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

**With `Input.GetAxis`**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Follower : MonoBehaviour {

    float distance = 10f;
    Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;
    float speed = .01f;
    Transform target;

    void Update() {
        direction *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.up);
        Ray ray = new Ray(target.position, direction);

        transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance);
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither quite worked for me, but I got the second one working without the animation part, it just appears at the right place when you point that direction on the stick, will post my code

Comment: Like i said, havent tested it but im sure the solution is inside that code somewhere with some minor adjustments ;)

Comment: Yeah, it was very helpful thanks :) I'm still chipping away at it :)